# How to get 3DSecure modal to work with Stripe Payment intents?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I can make the payments work for test cards NOT requiring 3DSecure authentication. For cards that require it, no modal pops up. In the dashboard the payments will show up with status "The customer must complete an additional authentication step." In these cases I don't even reach the

```
then(function(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        alert(result.error.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Success!');
```

code part. With non-3ds test cards, this part is working fine.
Debugging the javascript will show me some meaningless exceptions from stripe js script.

Given that it works for some cards, the server site initialization of the payment intent, and passing of the clientsecret, can be ruled out, that part works.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 930px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>           
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenClientSecret" runat="server" />
        <input id="cardholder-name" type="text"/>
        <!-- placeholder for Elements -->
        <div id="card-element" class="auto-style1"></div>
        <button id="card-button">
          Submit Payment
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<script >
    var stripe = Stripe('mykey', {locale: 'en'});
    var elements = stripe.elements({locale: 'en'});
    var cardElement = elements.create('card', {hidePostalCode: true});
    cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
    var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    var clientSecret = document.getElementById('hiddenClientSecret').value;
    cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        stripe.handleCardPayment(
                clientSecret, cardElement, {
                    payment_method_data: {
                    billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
                  }
                }
            ).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Success!');
                }
            });
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: Can you add to your post how you have initialized Stripe.js in the head? 
The error you should be seeing is Stripe.js is not initialized properly, but you are referencing it later.

Comment: Code updated - added this: ```<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 930px;
        }
    </style>
</head>```

Comment: The stripe.js must be initialized properly - it works for non-3dsecure cards!

Comment: Martin, which 3DS card you are using for testing? Some the testing card might require you to use Radar rules to make 3DS shows up.

Comment: I tried 4000002760003184 - This test card requires authentication on all transactions. AND 4000000000003220 - 3D Secure 2 authentication must be completed on all transactions.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I needed to explicitly set button type to "button" - otherwise it does a submit roundtrip to the server: `<button type="button" id="card-button">`. That code part was taken directly from Stripe, seems they need to be a little more precise in their docs!